How to use createCloseAccountInstruction to close TOKEN-2022 ? Using @solana/spl-token
Now i am using createCloseAccountInstruction of @solana/spl-token to close empty Token account .
My code working fine for TOKEN-PROGRAM .
But when i try to swith into TOKEN-2022 and call the createCloseAccountInstruction . it will told me
WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x23

Which means the transaction it build have problem ...
Here are how my code works :
            const associatedAddress = new PublicKey(toClose);
            const closeInstruction = await createCloseAccountInstruction(              
              associatedAddress,
              publickey,
              publickey,
              [],
              // TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
              TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
            );
            Tx.add(closeInstruction);

When i use it to burn with TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID , it works fine .
But when i switch it into TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID , it failed ...

createCloseAccountInstruction(
  account,
  destination,
  authority,
  multiSigners,
  // use this:
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
)

is the corect signature for the function, however, you get error 0x23, which is hex 35, so it's the 35 error message in here:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/0ab6ed7869679c0f5e2a72068e7a4e0591076d1f/token/program-2022/src/error.rs#L139C5-L143C36
//  35
/// An account can only be closed if its withheld fee balance is zero,
/// harvest fees to the mint and try again


Thanks to your informations !

But when i try the same code but using TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID to handel SPLTOKEN close account , it works .  It just not work when i switch it into TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID during the time i try close the token 2022 account

And i have try print the associatedAddress out , which is correct and point to one of the PDA address of my TOKEN-2022
4ASJHVwiKa9Ag32pjq4g2SZKmYbmuwANNaA37bmvms8b
anyway, the code i upload there means : close the associatedAddress and take the SOL back to my publickey . Which have no multiSigners during this process i think .
